# Functions $C^1[a,b]$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

In the definition of the set $C^1[a,b]$ do we assume that if $f \in C^1[a,b]$, then $f$ is defined on an open interval containing $a$ and $f'(a)$ exists?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is an element of $\mathcal{C}^1[0,1]$ and called *continuously differentiable* if and only if it is differentiable and has a continuous derivative.

Thus, $f\in \mathcal{C}^1[0,1]$ means that:

- $f$ is a real function defined on $[0,1]$,
- $f'(a)$ exists for all $a \in [0,1]$, and
- the derivative $f': a \mapsto f'(a)$ is a continuous function.

Comment: But, to define the derivative of $f$ at $0$ we need that $f$ is defined on an open interval containing $0$. That's right?

Comment: That's a good observation. Here, $f'(0)$ and $f'(1)$ are the right and left derivatives, respectively.

Comment: The fact that they exist implies that $f$ can be extended to a function in $\mathcal{C}^1(-\varepsilon, 1+\varepsilon)$ for some small $\varepsilon > 0$.

Comment: And, are the derivatives of that extension at $0$ and $1$ equal to the lateral derivatives of $f$ at $0$ and $1$,  respectively?

Comment: Yes, precisely. But this extension is not very important.